# Alternative procedure to prerender(not using prerender.io) in htaccess. Full custom code recommended

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular6, prerender

Is there any alternative procedure not to use prerender.io or custom way to implement it by writing code in htaccess? Need help. I am using angular 4 and apache server in back. Prerender.io asking for subscriptions.Please if anyone can help me writing the same custom code in htaccess.Here is my code in htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://weedbuys.com/api/$1 [P,L]
# Prerender.io stuff
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Baiduspider|DoCoMo|Twitterbot|
TweetmemeBot|Twikle|Netseer|Daumoa|SeznamBot|Ezooms|MSNBot|Exabot|MJ12bot|sogou\
sspider|bitlybot|ia_archiver|proximic|spbot|ChangeDetection|NaverBot|MetaJobBot|magpiecrawler|Genieo\sWeb\sfilter|Qualidator.com\sBot|Woko|Vagabondo|360Spider|ExB\
sLanguage\sCrawler|AddThis.com|aiHitBot|Spinn3r|BingPreview|GrapeshotCrawler|
CareerBot|ZumBot|ShopWiki|bixocrawler|uMBot|sistrix|linkdexbot|AhrefsBot|archive.
org_bot|SeoCheckBot|TurnitinBot|VoilaBot|SearchmetricsBot|Butterfly|
Yahoo!|Plukkie|yacybot|trendictionbot|UASlinkChecker|Blekkobot|Wotbox|YioopBot|
meanpathbot|TinEye|LuminateBot|FyberSpider|Infohelfer|linkdex.com|Curious\sGeorge|FetchGuess|ichiro|MojeekBot|SBSearch|WebThumbnail|socialbm_bot|SemrushBot|Vedma|alexa\ssite\
saudit|SEOkicks-Robot|Browsershots|BLEXBot|woriobot|AMZNKAssocBot|Speedy|oBot|
HostTracker|OpenWebSpider|WBSearchBot|FacebookExternalHit [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
# Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|
\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.
mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.
dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://weedbuys.com/$2
[P,L]
</IfModule>
# Don't rewrite files or directories, but exclude adminer directory
RewriteRule ^(adminer)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^adminer - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: *the same custom code* - but you didn't show any code

Comment: I've included the code- @barbsan